# Variable inheritance in Java (Beginner)

Tags: java, variables, inheritance

I have a class A with a variable `bool var = true` and a getter method `getVar()`.
I'm trying to create a class B that extends A and redefines var to `bool var = false`. The code:

```
public class A{
    protected boolean var = true;
    public boolean getVar(){
        return var;
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    protected boolean var = false;
}
```

The problem is that if I execute:

```
B b_class = new B();
System.out.println(b_class.getVar());
```

I obtain `true` and I don't undestand why. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't do `B.getVar()`, since the method isn't static. I assume you mean `b_class.getVar()` and fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating a new instance variable in your overridden class, because it can't be seen by the super class (A), and therefore when `getVar()` is called, it will return the value it can see. You should instead be setting the value of `var` in the constructor to be what you want.

```
public B() {
    var = false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't "inherit" variables; `B.var` merely hides `A.var`, but only in `B`. You are calling `getVar()`, a method in `A`, which sees `A.var`, which is `true`.

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a new `var` field in `B` that is hiding `A.var`. Try this instead:

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        var = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable initialized in the super class can’t be changed like this. You have already declared protected boolean var = true. So, no matter what you do in extended class it will always show you true.

Answer (score 0):

GetVar isn't defined in B so polymorphism jumps to A where var is true.